# Compare 2 mongodb fields before creating user (passportjs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using passportjs in my express app, and I've just implemented the code that checks mongoDB to see if 'email' or 'businessName' are already registered. My code is mostly working so I'm only going to provide the part of it I think is necessary.

```
 User.findOne({
            $or: [
              { username: { $regex: req.body.username, $options: "i" } },
              {
                businessName: { $regex: req.body.businessName, $options: "i" },
              },
            ],
          }).then((person) => {
            // email or businessName already exist
            if (person) {
              res.render("signup", {
                exists: "This email is already registered",
                info: req.body,
                errors: errorsObj,
                msg: "Please check the form for errorsss",
              });
            } else {
              const user = new User({
                businessName: req.body.businessName,
                username: req.body.username,
                password: theHash,
              });
              user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
                //succesful - redirect to login
                res.redirect("/login");
              });
            }
          });
```

As you can see I search for 2 fields, and use the 'exists' variable to render the error message to my ejs. However I would like to be able to display 2 separate messages, one for if a 'username' already exists, and one for if a 'businessName' already exists. I've also tried to set it up so I do 2 separate searches, one for 'username' and one for 'businessName', but I feel like if I can avoid calling an extra search that'd be good.

I've tried the following code:

```
User.findOne({
  $or: [
    { username: { $regex: req.body.username, $options: "i" } },
    {
      businessName: { $regex: req.body.businessName, $options: "i" },
    },
  ],
}).then((person) => {
  // businessName already exists
   if ( person.businessName ===  req.body.businessName ) {
    res.render("signup", {
      businessTaken: 'this business is taken',
      info: req.body,
      errors: errorsObj,
      msg: "Please check the form for errors",
    });
   }
// username already exists
  else if ( person.username === req.body.username ){
    res.render("signup", {
      emailTaken: 'this email is taken',
      info: req.body,
      errors: errorsObj,
      msg: "Please check the form for errors",
    });
 }

 else if ( person.businessName ===  req.body.businessName && person.username === req.body.username) {
  res.render("signup", {
    bothEmail: 'email taken',
    bothBusiness: 'this business is taken',
    info: req.body,
    errors: errorsObj,
    msg: "Please check the form for errors",
  });
 }
```

but i get `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Am I approaching this problem the wrong way? am i better off just just doing 2 different searches? any help is greatly appreciated

update:

```
// without if statements
exports.signup__post = [
  body("businessName")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
  body("username").trim().isEmail().withMessage("Invalid email address"),
  body("password").isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("enter pass"),


  sanitizeBody("*").escape(),

  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    let errArray = errors.array();

    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.render("signup", {
        info: req.body,
        errors: errArray,
        msg: "Please check the form for errors",
      });
      return;
    } else {
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        } else {
          let theHash = hashedPassword;
          // User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
          User.findOne({
            $or: [
              { username: { $regex: req.body.username, $options: "i" } },
              {
                businessName: { $regex: req.body.businessName, $options: "i" },
              },
            ],
          }).then((person) => {
            if (person) {
              res.render("signup", {
                emailTaken: "This email is already registered",
                info: req.body,
                errors: errorsObj,
                msg: "Please check the form for errors",
              });
            } else {
              const user = new User({
                businessName: req.body.businessName,
                username: req.body.username,
                password: theHash,
              });
              user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
                //succesful - redirect to login
                res.redirect(
                  "/login/?message=" +
                    "Your account was created, please login to continue"
                );
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  },
];
```

```
//with if statements

exports.signup__post = [
  body("businessName")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage("Please enter the name of your business"),
  body("username").trim().isEmail().withMessage("Invalid email address"),
  body("password").isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage("enter pass"),


  sanitizeBody("*").escape(),

  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    let errArray = errors.array();


    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.render("signup", {
        info: req.body,
        errors: errArray,
        msg: "Please check the form for errors",
      });
      return;
    } else {
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        } else {
          let theHash = hashedPassword;
          // User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
          User.findOne({
            $or: [
              { username: { $regex: req.body.username, $options: "i" } },
              {
                businessName: { $regex: req.body.businessName, $options: "i" },
              },
            ],
          }).then((person) => {
            if (person) {
              res.render("signup", {
                emailTaken: "This email is already registered",
                info: req.body,
                errors: errorsObj,
                msg: "Please check the form for errors",
              });

              // businessName already exists
              if (person.businessName === req.body.businessName) {
                res.render("signup", {
                  businessTaken: "this business is taken",
                  info: req.body,
                  errors: errorsObj,
                  msg: "Please check the form for errors",
                });
              }
              // username already exists
              else if (person.username === req.body.username) {
                res.render("signup", {
                  emailTaken: "this email is taken",
                  info: req.body,
                  errors: errorsObj,
                  msg: "Please check the form for errors",
                });
              } else if (
                person.businessName === req.body.businessName &&
                person.username === req.body.username
              ) {
                res.render("signup", {
                  bothEmail: "email taken",
                  bothBusiness: "this business is taken",
                  info: req.body,
                  errors: errorsObj,
                  msg: "Please check the form for errors",
                });
              }
            } else {
              const user = new User({
                businessName: req.body.businessName,
                username: req.body.username,
                password: theHash,
              });
              user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
                //succesful - redirect to login
                res.redirect(
                  "/login/?message=" +
                    "Your account was created, please login to continue"
                );
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  },
];
```

Comment: Looks like the execution flow outside the database call returns the response and once the response is sent back to the client the response object can't be write no more. Please share the enclosing part so that the exact flow could be identified.

Comment: @MostafizRahman hey I updated the post with the enclosing code. thanks for taking a look, i appreciate it

Comment: use return in your response objects